# using inner namespace in outer namespace without reopening outer namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17

Consider a library who defines its own global namespace `::libx` and then has nested namespaces `ns1`, `ns2`, etc.:

```
// lib code
namespace libx
{
    namespace ns1
    {
        struct X1{};
    }

    namespace ns2
    {
        struct X2{};
    }
}
```

Is there a way to qualify all uses of the lib with its global namespace, but omit the nested namespaces? Like so:

```
// user code
auto test()
{
    // using ????

    libx::X1 x1{};
    libx::X2 x2{};
}
```

The only way I can think of is to reopen its global namespace:

```
// user code
namespace libx // reopening lib's namespace
{
    using namespace ns1;
    using namespace ns2;
}
```

But this can be illegal (e.g. `namespace std` in the standard library) (and even if it's not explicitly made illegal I think can break the lib now or the future - I mean, there must be a reason why C++ prohibits it for the standard library)  and cannot be done locally (inside a single function for instance)

---

Alternative I thought of:

Rename each of the nested namespace:

```
// user code
auto test()
{
    namespace libx1 = libx::ns1;
    namespace libx2 = libx::ns2;

    libx1::X1 x1{};
    libx2::X2 x2{};
}
```

But this has different qualifiers for each nested namespace.

Create a new global namespace where you bring all nested namespaces:

```
//user code:
namespace libx_all
{
    using namespace libx;
    using namespace libx::ns1;
    using namespace libx::ns2;
}

auto test()
{
    namespace libx1 = libx::ns1;

    libx_all::X1 x1{};
    libx_all::X2 x2{};
}
```

This actually I think comes relatively close to the goal, but it feels like a hack, can spawn confusion and cannot be done locally (inside a single function for instance). Besides those, are there other disadvantages to look for (like messing ADL)?

Comment: Just to be clear. We have no control over how the library code is defined, correct?

Comment: @StoryTeller correct, I am just a consumer of the library.

Comment: I don't think any of this changes the behavior of ADL. The namespace where the type _actually_ is matters, not any aliases of it. (Otherwise, any code that does `using namespace std;` would not be able to perform ADL on any types in `std` which would surely break a bunch of stuff.) Your `libx_all` approach is probably the cleanest approach out of these, but beware that it will break if you try to use something that has a conflicting name in multiple imported namespaces.

Comment: Why not just use something like `using namespace libx::ns2;` inside your function? Wouldn't that achieve sort of the same effect as something like `namespace libx2 = libx::ns2;`?

Comment: @Chipster I don't want the names to be unqualified.

Comment: @bolov Ah. That makes sense.